# How to align images side by side as well as vertically without gaps?

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to align some images side by side without have gaps vertically. 
Each image width is 20% of the page (5 per a row), and the height varies between the images.


Is there any way of aligning them vertically as well (so that each image is directly below the one above it without a gap, as because of the random heights, all images on a row start where the photo with the largest height above ends)?

css for the photo

```
     .photo {width:20%; height:auto;         
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        float:left;
       }
```

the photo

```
   <img src="" alt="image" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%;" class="photo">
```

Comment: Please check this, created one fiddle for you.

https://jsfiddle.net/satyaprasanna/txtd3zdr/1/

Comment: What you're describing sounds like a masonry layout. You can use plugins for that, or if you want pure CSS this might help you --> https://medium.com/@_jh3y/how-to-pure-css-masonry-layouts-a8ede07ba31a

Comment: @satya the images have random heights.

Comment: What you're looking for is called *masonry layout*. [Masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/) library can help you achieve that pretty easily. I don't think we can achieve that using css floats, that's why I'm linking to a js library.

Comment: @ovokuro Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

you can emulate table, and for cell set vertical-align:middle;

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="cell">
        <img src="" alt="image" class="photo">
    </div>
  ...
</div>
```

and css for it

```
.table{
    display: table;
}
.cell { 
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.photo{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%
}
```

example https://jsfiddle.net/nardist01/2f7yd20e/2/

Answer (score 0):

you see the example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Manoj1991/txtd3zdr/2/)

```
.photo {
        width:20%; 
        height:auto;         
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        float:left;
       }
```